# In Python, how could I get a user input while simultaneously running the script?

Tags: python, chat, user-input, raw-input

In my program I am trying to take the chat from a website and printing it on my console. While that's going on I'm using raw_input to get chat from whoever is using it. My problem is that raw_input pauses the rest of the script until i say something or press enter. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You have to multithread. One thread for user input and another for the background tasks.

The documentation is a bit complex (I'm pretty confused by it), but it's a start: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Comment: nah multi threading is a little to skilled for my level :p but i'll try to use that as last resort

Comment: It's quite intuitive if you ask me. Look at this example: http://www.wellho.net/solutions/python-python-threads-a-first-example.html

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to look into the curses module: http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html

Comment: You don't need to install it. `import curses` is all you need to do, curses ships with Python.