# How do have processes running periodically while waiting for input from user in python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have something waiting for user input

```
input("Name:")
```

Is it possible to run a few other things while waiting for the user's input? Like print some things based on newly acquired information from API etc, all while waiting on the input from the user.

Comment: input is a blocking function, and also try threading. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006669/in-python-how-could-i-get-a-user-input-while-simultaneously-running-the-script

Comment: What about something that time outs input after 5 seconds? i havn't found a way to do that in windows either.

Comment: This should help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-raw-input